# Self hosted GitHub Action Runner jobs failing

Tags: docker, github-actions, github-actions-runners

We make use of Github Self-Hosted action runners running on EC2 machines (m5.xlarge). We use these as part of our CI/CD pipeline to support docker image builds and automated testing. This solution has worked fine for the last year or so, but all of a sudden yesterday, the builds started to fail with the following error message :

`time="2023-02-03T12:00:13Z" level=error msg="error waiting for container: unexpected EOF"`

My understanding of this is that it is typically due to docker containers running out of resources (CPU / Memory Limit) being hit but given that these are m5.xlarges (4 vCPU and 16GB Memory) I'm a little surprised. Our builds make use of NPM which I understand can be quite resource hungry but monitoring a container during its execution showed that it was nowhere near the limits of the node:

[image]

I've tried to cycle the nodes but there is no difference in behaviour. The following user-data script is used with these nodes which connects it to our Github account and makes it available for jobs. I've also tried using the latest actions-runneer package, but again, no change in behaviour. What other reasons could this error be thrown for as i'm a bit stumped by this.

```
#!/bin/sh
set -e

curl https://get.docker.com | bash
apt install -y python3-pip jq
pip3 install awscli

mkdir actions-runner && cd actions-runner
curl -O -L https://github.com/actions/runner/releases/download/v2.286.0/actions-runner-linux-x64-2.286.0.tar.gz
tar xzf ./actions-runner-linux-x64-2.286.0.tar.gz
chown -R ubuntu:ubuntu .

instance_id="$(curl -s http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id)"

url="https://api.github.com/orgs/<REMOVED>/actions/runners/registration-token"
token=$(curl -s -u "<REMOVED>:<REMOVED>" -X POST "$url" | jq -r .token)

sudo -u ubuntu ./config.sh \
  --name "products-stage-ec2-runner-$instance_id" \
  --token "$token" \
  --url "https://github.com/<REMOVED>" \
  --labels "<REMOVED>" \
  --unattended

sudo ./svc.sh install
sudo ./svc.sh start
```

Comment: Hello, did you ever find out the cause of this? We're experiencing the same issue.

Comment: Hi @WillJenkins yes I did. It looks like this was due to a problem in Docker 23.0 as documented in the following bug ticket (https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/44918). Since we use the Docker convienience script as part of our EC2 user-data, when a node cycles down and up again, it was pulling the latest version of Docker, hence why this started all of a sudden for us with no code or deployment changes. I've modified our user-data script and locked the Docker install to 20.10 and the problem is resolved for us. Hope this helps you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See details on my comment of how I resolved this.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).